# Call a Google Cloud function written in python from Android client?

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions

I am running google cloud functions that i would like to call from my android app.

I am using gcloud CLI to deploy my functions which are written in Python. I would then like to call this function from my android app via the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). I am not sure if this will work though because it doesn't mention python [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) *"Your JavaScript or TypeScript code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment."* i.e. only JavaScript or TypeScript functions work?

Is there any way to get around this so that I can call python code from the android app? Will changing the Firebase Dependency `com.google.firebase:firebase-functions-ktx` to the Google Cloud Platform dependency `com.google.cloud.functions:functions-framework-api:1.0.1` in my gradle file enable it to work? Or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: If you're deploying an HTTP function with Cloud Functions, just invoke it with whatever HTTP library you want on the client just like any other web api. It doesn't matter what language the function is written in.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am running a task following changes to a firestore collection [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75961087/15597975). Are cloud functions the best tool for this database operation or is there any google cloud product specific to returning a result from database operation? I previously was using SQL to handle the large database on my android client as found it was much quicker then kotlin for loops. Wondering if running the kotlin for loop on cloud functions is best or if there are other google cloud api's/tools for this type of large database work?

Comment: Recommendations for tools and requests for opinions about them are both off-topic for Stack Overflow.  You should ask on a forum that does allow those types of questions, such as Reddit.